# Unable to send emails on Godaddy production. It's Working on local.!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, smtp, web-hosting

I have seen solutions here but **they don't work for me**. 
I have also used different ports but no luck. 
Also contacted with godaddy service they said its all good on server side.
Also tried many code but no luck either.

**"Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."**

Any suggestions would be helpful.!!

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@domain.com"); 
mail.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "My subject"
mail.Body = "My body"
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
//smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@domain.com", "****");
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Please provide the code

Comment: have a look at this http://docs.mailpoet.com/article/54-guide-to-sending-from-a-godaddy-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After 2 months i finally got the solution for this problem.**

i was trying different ports with different codes too and publishing every time, but no solution.

One day i eventually published my complied `projectName.dll` file too and then guess what i sent emails successfully.

sometime we do the right steps but little things like these matters a lot.